# Best screen resolution page width 1200px on most devices on 2015

Tags: android, css, html, resolution

I have a liquid flexible layout with 3 columns, on left 200px and right 200px but even if the page support infinite width I would like to set a standard 2015 for center column main content.

800px nobody uses it but the question is if 1000px is also old and mostly uses 1300px or what do you recoomend?

I tested with 1000px width and it works fine on many cellphones and tablets (horizontal view) but it seems like even old notebooks and netbooks supports 1300px.

What do you recoomend and which screen resolution is the most popular on year 2015 including old devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally use 1200px (with padding goes to 1180px), but 1300px works fine, too. Just make sure your website is responsive, then no one will have problems.